# WinVerifyTrust only works when using a file not a memory blob

Tags: c++, winapi, winverifytrust

I am trying to the `WinVerifyTrust` function to verify the signature of a msi.

And while this works for files on the file system I cannot get it to work with a memory blob.
This basis of my example to show the problem is the example program from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program--verifying-the-signature-of-a-pe-file)

```
BOOL VerifyEmbeddedSignature(LPCWSTR pwszSourceFile)
{
   std::basic_ifstream<BYTE> file(pwszSourceFile, std::ios::binary);
  std::vector<BYTE> data((std::istreambuf_iterator<BYTE>(file)),std::istreambuf_iterator<BYTE>());

  LONG lStatus;

  /*
  // this works
  WINTRUST_FILE_INFO FileData;
  memset(&FileData, 0, sizeof(FileData));
  FileData.cbStruct = sizeof(WINTRUST_FILE_INFO);
  FileData.pcwszFilePath = pwszSourceFile;
  FileData.hFile = NULL;
  FileData.pgKnownSubject = NULL;
  */
  WINTRUST_BLOB_INFO FileData{};
  memset(&FileData, 0, sizeof(FileData));
  FileData.cbStruct = sizeof(WINTRUST_BLOB_INFO);
  FileData.gSubject = WIN_TRUST_SUBJTYPE_RAW_FILE;
  FileData.cbMemObject = static_cast<DWORD>(data.size());
  FileData.pbMemObject = data.data();

  GUID WVTPolicyGUID = WINTRUST_ACTION_GENERIC_VERIFY_V2;
  WINTRUST_DATA WinTrustData;
  memset(&WinTrustData, 0, sizeof(WinTrustData));
  WinTrustData.cbStruct = sizeof(WinTrustData);
  WinTrustData.pPolicyCallbackData = NULL;
  WinTrustData.pSIPClientData = NULL;
  WinTrustData.dwUIChoice = WTD_UI_NONE;
  WinTrustData.fdwRevocationChecks = WTD_REVOKE_NONE;
  //WinTrustData.dwUnionChoice = WTD_CHOICE_FILE; -- works
  WinTrustData.dwUnionChoice = WTD_CHOICE_BLOB;
  WinTrustData.dwStateAction = WTD_STATEACTION_VERIFY;
  WinTrustData.hWVTStateData = NULL;
  WinTrustData.pwszURLReference = NULL;
  WinTrustData.dwUIContext = 0;
  WinTrustData.pBlob = &FileData;
  //WinTrustData.pFile = &FileData; -- works

  lStatus = WinVerifyTrust(
    NULL,
    &WVTPolicyGUID,
    &WinTrustData);

  WinTrustData.dwStateAction = WTD_STATEACTION_CLOSE;
  WinVerifyTrust(
    NULL,
    &WVTPolicyGUID,
    &WinTrustData);

  return lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

In the above example using the `WINTRUST_FILE_INFO` works but the `WINTRUST_BLOB_INFO` does not.
The error that I get with a memory blob is always `TRUST_E_PROVIDER_UNKNOWN`.

I assume that the problem might be the `WIN_TRUST_SUBJTYPE_RAW_FILE` subject type but I don't know which one I should use for a msi file.
I am wondering if the sign check is possible at all with memory blobs of msi files.

Comment: if its a memory blob, why are you specifying raw file?

Comment: From doc: gSubject

The GUID of the SIP to load.

Comment: @stark As I stated I guess the RAW_FILE is wrong. But I only have raw, pe, java_class and cabinet file. None of those seem to fit and none of those works. So I still assume that this is the problem, but I cannot find what would be the right SIP to load. Or if there is a SIP at all.

Comment: You could try to use [`CryptSIPRetrieveSubjectGuid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mssip/nf-mssip-cryptsipretrievesubjectguid) to retrieve the subject guid for the specified file.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT Great Idea. And it solved my issue. The method returns `{ 0x000C10F1, 0x0000, 0x0000,  {0xC0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x46} }` and using this sip thems to works. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Glad to help, and since it does solve your issue, I will convert the comment to an answer. You could feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WIN_TRUST_SUBJTYPE_RAW_FILE` is not the suitable subject GUID. You could The function [`CryptSIPRetrieveSubjectGuid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mssip/nf-mssip-cryptsipretrievesubjectguid) retrieves a GUID based on the header information in a specified file.